# Salesforce and Excel - Favorite tools for one-click reports

Tags: discussion

As much as I don't like to, I find myself getting dragged into providing **one click** solutions for users who demand their Salesforce output in pretty Excel worksheets.

This question is:

"**What tools you use to accomplish this?**"

```
(and, making the guy/gal in sales ops do the bloody work is, 
 unfortunately, a tool that doesn't work for me in my current org)
```

Options I have some familiarity with:

1. Salesforce Report exported to Excel using **Printable View** - this doesn't pass the straight face test.  The resulting Excel output is unmanipulable.
2. **Conga Composer** - Nice ability to place multiple SFDC reports and queries onto a single worksheet. One click reports from a link on sidebar or page layout. Fragile binding (not point-and-click) between your Composer template and your SFDC reports/queries.  Lots-o-Conga parameters to learn (e.g. `&DV7= ...`). Costs $$ (especially if you have many users who need this)
3. **Power Query for Excel (free)** - As of Dreamforce 14, the SFDC connector was added. This is a pretty cool tool although you have to learn a new ribbon for Excel and a new Excel language ("M") to do anything not provided by the ribbon tools. At least as far as I've used it, you need to be using 64 bit Excel to avoid running out of memory.  The nice thing is that Power Query allows you to move construction of calculations away from custom formula fields in your schema into new columns created on the fly in Excel. Once data is loaded, you can manipulate with Power Pivot, Power View, and Power Maps.  An important contrast with Conga is that users have to start from the workbook to launch their refreshed "excel report/dashboard" instead of clicking on a link in Salesforce.

I've also seen (but never done) taking SFDC Report(s) Export Details, copy/pasting into Excel workbooks that have macros and VBA and transforming the data this way - but this isn't really a one-click solution

Comment: My personal choice has been Conga products. Conga has awesome support and easy to use product. Though I agree that they have way too many params, but I would love to go back to conga any given time

Comment: yes, their (Conga) support is first rate; telephone support no less, and an intense desire to make sure they solve your issue

Comment: [Apttus's X-Author for Excel](http://x-author.com/) is fantastic.